# Adding variable to be displayed in tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I want to write an app that displays current Bitcoin price next to current time. I am new to python and tkinter and I don't know how to add the Bitcoin variable next to time.

```
import requests
btc = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
btc_price = (btc.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate'])
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from time import strftime
root = Tk()
root.title('Btc')
label = Label(root, font = ('arial', 40, 'bold'), background = 'white', foreground = 'black')
def time():
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
    label.config(text = string)
    label.after(1000, time)   
label.pack(anchor = 'center')
time()
mainloop()
```

I can only get it to display time.

Comment: Next as in below or to the side?

Comment: `label['text'] = label['text'] + string` or shorter `label['text'] += string`. Using `config()` - `label.config(text = label.cget('text') + string)`

Comment: or maybe simply `label.config(text = string + " " + btc_price )`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you wanted.

```py
#imports
import requests
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from time import strftime

#Canvas preparation
root = Tk()
root.title('Btc')
label = Label(root, font = ('arial', 40, 'bold'), background = 'white', foreground = 'black')
label2 = Label(root, font = ('arial', 40, 'bold'), background = 'white', foreground = 'black')

#Looper/Updater method
def time():
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
    #value request
    btc = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
    btc_price = (btc.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate']) # You might wanna keep the value updated, right?
    #Assigning values to label for updating.
    label.config(text = string)
    label2.config(text=btc_price)
    #recursive rendition loop
    label.after(1000, time)
#Use the coordinate system as opposed to anchor system to place the values.
#Here I have taken LEFT side edge as reference, you might wanna change per aesthetic appeal.
label.pack(padx=5, pady=10, side=LEFT)
label2.pack(padx=5, pady=20, side=RIGHT)

#Recursive rendition call
time()

#Exhibit
mainloop()
```

Comment: you should describe what you did.